# Unhandled Exception: [core/duplicate-app] A Firebase App named "[DEFAULT]" already exists

Tags: firebase, flutter

[1]what solution of this error ? s

Unhandled Exception: [core/duplicate-app] A Firebase App named "[DEFAULT]" already exists
E/flutter (18435):
MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp
(package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:113:11)

Comment: Please add your code code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the firebase app initialisation in a try-catch like so:

```
void main() async{
 try {
   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   await Firebase.initializeApp();
 } catch (e) {}
 runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: in catch curly brackets add body of main ?

Comment: What is it doesn't throw error? it won't runApp

Comment: It will @MehrdadShokri, the runApp is outside the try-catch block.

Comment: Yes, yes you're right. But app will throw error indicating Firebase has not been initialized.